# NoClassDefFoundError with java reflection

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

I am using the following code to dynamically load a class in java:

```
URL url = new File(ACTIONS_PATH).toURI().toURL();
URLClassLoader clazzLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{url});
Class<RatingAction> clazz =  (Class<RatingAction>) clazzLoader.loadClass(name);
return clazz.newInstance();
```

This code works with simple classes (no inheritance or interfaces), but the class I want to load is implementing an interface (that the class loader can find using `findClass`)
and when i call class.newInstance I get the mentioned exception.
What am i doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure about your problem, but to write `Class<RatingAction>`, you should be loading the class `RatingAction`, but this type must be loaded already for you to write this. Do you mean `Class<? extends RatingAction>`?

Comment: I was able to circumvent the problem by simple using `Class.forname(name).newInstance` but i would be happy to understand why the original code didnt work

Comment: Because this time you didn't use the custom cloassloader.

Comment: Does this same URLClassLoader you are using here is able to find the interface?

Comment: @Paulo Yes the classloader can find the interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have problems with your classpath. My guess it happens since you don't define the parent classloader - does "url" contains all the needed classes including the system classes?

You are getting the exception, when the class is actually resolved, so the classes that appear in the loaded class are also loaded. If you change `clazzLoader.loadClass(name)` to `clazzLoader.loadClass(name, true)`, you will get the exception in loadClass line.

Try the following:

```
URL url = new File(ACTIONS_PATH).toURI().toURL();
URLClassLoader clazzLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{url}, getClass().getClassLoader());
Class<RatingAction> clazz =  (Class<RatingAction>) clazzLoader.loadClass(name);
return clazz.newInstance();
```